# Java application is not showing correctly in Linux Ubuntu 22.04, characterset issues

Tags: java, encoding

I have developed a java application under windows where I didn't faced any problems. But now I had to switch to Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop) and I see a problem. When the application starts under Windows (tested on 10 and 11) it works perfectly as it should. But when I start it on Ubuntu, symbols and German Characters are not rendered correctly.

In all cases, Operating-Systems are installed with German Language as default.
Application is being run with same JDK (OpenJDK 11) in all cases.

What I can guess is, it is some sort of encoding-issue, but I have tried what I could find on internet but so far without success.

[Shots of application parts on Windows and Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoPK9.png)

I am expecting the app render correctly on both Windows and Linux, and especially find out what is wrong and how to avoid it in future.

Comment: I have also tried `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -Dsun.jnu.encoding="UTF-8"` as CLI argument, without any success.

Comment: But as far as I can understand, Ubuntu is already using UTF-8, for example


`System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());`

gives me **UTF-8**

Comment: I guess your GUI Application specifies a specific font, which is only available on Windows, but not on Linux.
You can try to install related fonts on Linux (copy from Windows)

Comment: That's exactly what it was, thanks @life888888. Changing the Font solved the issue.

My application was was using Segoe UI Font, native to Windows.
I actually had found the font on Internet for Ubuntu and installed it, but perhaps since it wasn't the original Font or whatever. It was causing the issue and since I had installed the Font, I would have never thought of it myself. Thanks a lot.

![Bildschirmfoto-vom-2023-03-16-11-39-36.png](https://tinypic.host/images/2023/03/16/Bildschirmfoto-vom-2023-03-16-11-39-36.png)